# building first custom CMS and have been told to use Dreamweaver and a plug in called Horizontal Looper

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, loops, dreamweaver

so I'm in a little over my head right now and want to verify that i've been given good advice as for how to build this simple CMS site. It's a book site and there's going to be a few image galleries (for example, one for characters) where the user clicks different thumbnails and a span with text descriptions and large images are revealed.

here's the plug-in i was instructed to buy:
http://www.tom-muck.com/extensions/help/HorizontalVerticalLooperHelp/

has anyone used this before? or does anyone have any other ideas as to how to go about doing this as quickly as possible? the deadline is about 2weeks away, and i just figured out how to build my databases with phpmyadmin.

thank you for reading :)

Comment: Oh my... Based on your link, I'm assuming you're building this from scratch.  With a two week deadline, I'd research FOSS projects for a week to find one that meets your needs and spend the second week configuring it.

Comment: Yeah. Two weeks out having just figured out phpMyAdmin is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: thanks for the input you guys. youve confirmed my fears but now i can at least stop wasting time and get down to some research.

if anyone has any experience configuring a CMS for the particular type of gallery im trying to create or something similar id GREATLY appreciate hearing your story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point I would strongly recommend not trying to build this from scratch.

Go with something "off the shelf."  Some good options are:

- Wordpress
- Stencil
- DJango
- Drupal

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the plugin you mentioned (I'm not much for using Dreamweaver) but it sounds like you could use Dreamweaver's existing page stuff

1. build a recordset
2. show x number of items per page
3. add First, previous, next, last links

Then, for each link use a simple jQuery modal dialog to do the display bit for you.
Some options for that...

- http://fancybox.net/
- http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
- http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html

Sounds like this is might do the trick and it's free stuff.

Comment: if the site wasnt already designed id be able to utilize one of these options, but the client has already approved and seen a basic html/css prototype and will expect that once its been completed.

thank you for your help though, i will definitely keep all of these in mind for future projects :)